# How to import OS X keyboard text shortcuts?

Tags: macos, ios, keyboard, shortcut

On OS X Yosemite and iOS 8, I use keyboard text shortcuts:

[image: Keyboard text shortcuts]

I have a large list of text shortcuts I would like to use.

1. Is it possible to import my shortcuts into the OS X/iOS list of shortcuts?
2. Where are my keyboard text shortcuts stored on my Mac?

Answer (score 3):

If you sign in with the same primary iCloud account on OS X and iOS, the list of shortcuts is synchronised automatically.

It's currently unknown where the shortcuts are stored. <sub>[source](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6451698)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

[Source](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204006)

Summary of steps:

**Export**

1. Open System Preferences > Keyboard > Text.
2. Select the shortcuts you want to export (or one and then use "Select All" from the Edit menu).
3. Drag the selected shortcuts to the desktop. This creates a file name *Text Substitutions.plist* that contains the substitutions you selected.

**Import**

1. Drag the *Text Substitutions.plist* file (created through *Export*) to the area of the System Preferences window where the text substitutions are shown (under Replace or With).